# Matching an input from a string of characters?

Tags: python, string, input

Suppose I have a string -> (a,b,c,1,2,3)

The user is to pick a character from that string, perhaps b?

```
PickCharacter=raw_input("Pick a character? ")
```

User inputs, 'b'

The code recognizes that 'b' is a character within the string and accepts the input.

Whereas if the user inputs 'f', the program would reject the input because that character is not within the string.

How can I determine if the user picks a one of the following characters from the list?

Comment: Like every other homework question, you tend to learn more if you first attempt a solution yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
string_list = strng.split(",")
if pick in string_list:
    print "Yep"
else:
    print "Nope"
```

Comment: ummm that wont quite do what he wants (but at least shows him a path forward)

Comment: Oh, I thought he had a list of strings, that's what it looks like....oh well....

Comment: assuming he does have the input he put in a string 'a' would not be found with your solution :P

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If he picks 'a' and list is ['able', 'andrew'], yes it won't work.

Comment: `Suppose I have a string -> (a,b,c,1,2,3)` ... so this solution would be ok if you stripped the parens ... as it stands it would match `(a` but i think OP just wanted `a` ... nit-picking but meh (I gave you +1 anyway)

Comment: Oh, I get ya.  I was assuming the parens were representing the list.  OK.  Well, a vague solution for a vague question, lol.  Thanks for the +1.  I'll find one of yours.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have those single string literals in a list:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']
```

Assume the user chooses a literal `'c'`:

```
if user_choice in my_list:
    print "Valid Choice"
else:    
    print "Please provide a valid input"
```

The point to note is you can use the **in** keyword to test if an element is present in a list, dictionary or even a string of multiple characters.

Comment: AAAAHHHHHHH!!  Fix your font!

Comment: Darn, now YOU are shouting too... :)

Comment: You may want to study [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a method called index

string_list.index(PickCharacter)

This will return what position the character they typed in is found in the string. If it's not found it will return a ValueError.

Comment: it does not return 0 for not found!

Comment: correct, sorry wrong language, my bad.

Comment: there is a language that returns 0 for index?

Comment: <0 *  anyways right because 0 would be the first section.